# get the sibling link class when the the other sibling link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 5 divs , in each divs there's two links as shown in the example below

```
    <div id="wrapper">
<a href="2332" class="first link1">Link1</a><a href="link2" class="link2">Link2</a>
   </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
<a href="1221" class="second link1">Link1</a><a href="link2" class="link2">Link2</a>
   </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
<a href="789" class="third link1">Link1</a><a href="link2" class="link2">Link2</a>
   </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
<a href="345" class="abc link1">Link1</a><a href="link2" class="link2">Link2</a>
   </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
<a href="123" class="bcd link1">Link1</a><a href="link2" class="link2">Link2</a>
   </div>
```

How can i use javascript/jquery to GET the CLASS of link1(inside the same div not others) when LINK2 is clicked.
Okay when i clicked the **third** div's **link2** link , it will give me "third" (excluding the link1 which is also a class).

the click function is:

```
$('.link2').click(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the first link immediately precedes the second, you can use [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get to the link and [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the value of the `class` attribute:

```
$('.link2').click(function(){
    var prevClass = $(this).prev().attr("class");
});
```

That will give you "third link1", because that's the value of the `class` attribute. If you only want the first part, you could split it:

```
var prevClass = $(this).prev().attr("class").split(" ")[0];
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7eGtx/5/).

Comment: @sm21guy, you should accept the questions in order to get a better rep here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selector. You can also use prev or next depending on your situation.